# Mixed effects model

Tags: regression, lme4, mixed-models

I'm having a hard time finding a mixed-effects model that will fit my data.

My data has the following structure:

1. Participants have been divided into two disjointed groups
2. Each participant performs multiple trials
3. There are 3 types of trials
4. All participants perform the same trials
5. During each trial, we collect a metric every 20 ms.

We want to account for the changes between the groups and trial types.

So far, I've tried
Target~Time*Trial*Group+(1+Trial+Time|Participant)+(1|Participant:Group:Trial)

but the model's NLL value is very low (-230K)

Would appreciate any help,
Thank you

Comment: Having collected data every 20ms, are you sure that a GAMM wouldn't be a better choice?

Comment: Your `Trial` variable is the type of trial (which has 3 possible values), right? Because if it is the trial number (say, 1-20 per Person), then that eats up a huge number of DFs.